# Update current page on submit

Tags: php, html

```
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php?module=membres&action=forum">
        <table id='forum'>
            <tr>
                <td>Choix de forums:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Programmation</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="forum" id="prog" value="prog"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Reseau</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="forum" id="reseau" value="reseau"></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
            <td>Etude</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="forum" id="etude" value="etude"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
         <input type="submit" value="Charger le forum">

    </form>
</body>



    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo $id;
}
?>
```

I am trying to make a form with radio buttons. When you click on submit after choosing your radio button, the current page is supposed to be "updated" and calling a function in my `$_POST['submit']`. The function is supposed to make appear a table with elements that it gets from the database. Now I am just trying to echo anything to see if my `isset` post is working or not but apparently no. I also need a way to keep my radio button clicked after the submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always false:

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

Because the form has no element with `name="submit"`.  You can simply add that to your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Charger le forum">
```

Comment: omg im so stupid.... and if i do echo $id, is the id of the clicked button supposed to appear?

Comment: From the codesnipped you posted above, @Iocho30 there is no definition of `$id`. If you want to figure out what kind of radiobutton was clicked, `echo $_POST['forum']` inside the if-block and you will see the value of the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use

```
var_dump($your_variable);
```

to debug PHP easlily. (There are better ways)

in order to make it more human readable, 
try enclosing var dump in "pre" tags like so

```
 <pre>
        var_dump($my_variable);
 <pre>
```